# XDMP-NONMIXEDCOMPLEXCONT when doing xpath in rest extension

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to do the following

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";     
let $options := <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
                    <additional-query>
                        <cts:collection-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
                            <cts:uri>http://ir.abbvienet.com/content-repo/type/envelope</cts:uri>
                        </cts:collection-query>
                    </additional-query>
                    <constraint name="gene">
                        <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                            <path-index>//Hit[@type='GENE']/@id</path-index>
                            <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                            <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
                            <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
                        </range>
                    </constraint>
                </options>

    return
    $options//search:constraint[@name='gene']
```

When I do this in query console it works fine.. but when I do the same in my **REST extension**, I get the following error

```
<error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version>
<error:message>Node has complex type with non-mixed complex content</error:message>
<error:format-string>XDMP-NONMIXEDCOMPLEXCONT: fn:data(&lt;constraint name="gene" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"&gt;&lt;range type="xs:string" facet="true"&gt;&lt;path-index&gt;//Hit[@type='GE...&lt;/constraint&gt;) -- Node has complex type with non-mixed complex content</error:format-string>
 <error:retryable>false</error:retryable>
<error:expr>fn:data(&lt;constraint name="gene" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"&gt;&lt;range type="xs:string" facet="true"&gt;&lt;path-index&gt;//Hit[@type='GE...&lt;/constraint&gt;)</error:expr>
 <error:data/>
<error:stack>
```

Any ideas on why this is the case ?

**** **EDIT Added my REST extension below** *************

```
module namespace repoTest = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/repoTest";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

declare default function namespace  "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";
declare option xdmp:mapping "false";

(: Function responding to GET method - must use local name 'get':)
declare function repoTest:get($context as map:map, $params  as map:map) as document-node()*
{

        let $out :=
            try{

            let $options := <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
                                <constraint name="gene">
                                    <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                                        <path-index>//Hit[@type='GENE']/@id</path-index>
                                        <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                                        <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
                                        <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
                                    </range>
                                </constraint>
                    </options>
            let $facetContraint :=  $options//search:constraint[@name='gene']
            let $_ := xdmp:log("facetContraint :" || $facetContraint)
                return $facetContraint
            }catch($ex) {
                let $log := xdmp:log("ERROR !!!!!")
                let $log := xdmp:log($ex)
                return ()
        }

    return document { $out }
};

(: Function responding to PUT method - must use local name 'put'. :)
declare function repoTest:put($context as map:map, $params  as map:map, $input as document-node()*) as document-node()?
{
    repoTest:notSupportedMsg($context)
};

(: Func responding to DELETE method - must use local name 'delete'. :)
declare function repoTest:delete($context as map:map,$params  as map:map) as document-node()?
{
    repoTest:notSupportedMsg($context)
};

(: Function responding to POST method - must use local name 'post'. :)
declare function repoTest:post($context as map:map, $params  as map:map,$input   as document-node()*) as document-node()*
{
    repoTest:notSupportedMsg($context)
};

declare private function repoTest:notSupportedMsg($context as map:map) as document-node()*
{
    let $_ := map:put($context, "output-status", (501, "Not Supported HTTP method"))
    let $output := json:object()
    let $errorResponse := json:object()
    let $_ := (
        map:put($errorResponse, "statusCode", 501),
        map:put($errorResponse, "message", "Not Supported HTTP method")
    )
    let $dummpy := map:put($output, "errorResponse", $errorResponse )
    return document {xdmp:to-json($output)}
};
```

Comment: The above code is not a valid REST extension. Can you show how you use the code in your REST extension?

Comment: I added my REST extension code, all I was doing is returning the output in my extension code

Comment: Can you also say something about how you invoke your REST extension? Are you by any chance passing in a `format=json` parameter? That could trigger some automatic conversion logic, and that is probably not anticipating XML, in particular XML in search namespace?

Comment: I am calling using curl `curl -u reader:reader http://10.239.12.85:8042/LATEST/resources/repoTest`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue, but don;t understand why this happens in Rest extension but not in query console.

In the REST extension, it was failing because of the default namespace to the $options, once this is removed it works.. the way I removed is

```
functx:change-element-ns-deep($options, '','')
```

It would be nice if someone can give an explanation as to why my code in the question, works in query console but not in REST extension,

Comment: The namespace issue here is not leaping out to me.  That said, instead of dynamically stripping out the default namespace, it might be better to use the explicit "search" namespace prefix on the options.

Comment: Will this affect anything with the search:search api when using this options file.. as in all of ML docs they specify the options with default namespace without any prefix

Comment: As long as default namespace is the same namespace as that of the search prefix, there is no difference. Using default namespace is just a means to make XML easier to read for humans..

Comment: if I add the `search` prefix, I think then I need to change all the elements in the options file to have prefix `search`